# how to include key in the result while parsing yaml file with yq command

Tags: yq

how to get values including the key? here is input:

```
istio_cni:
  enabled: false
  repair:
    enabled: true

istiocoredns:
  enabled: false

global:
  hub: docker.io/istio
  tag: 1.4.5
  logging:
    level: "default:info"
```

expected output is whole `global` block:

```
global:
  hub: docker.io/istio
  tag: 1.4.5
  logging:
    level: "default:info"
```

`yq` gives the result which doesn't include `global` key:

```
$ yq r /tmp/values.yaml global
hub: docker.io/istio
tag: 1.4.5
logging:
  level: "default:info"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the answer from yq author

```
$ yq r /tmp/values.yaml global -p pv
global:
  hub: docker.io/istio
  tag: 1.4.5
  logging:
    level: "default:info"
```

```
-p is for print mode

pv is one of a print mode - (v (values, default), p (paths), pv (path and value pairs) (default "v")
```

Comment: How is this done in yq v4+?

Comment: @HendrikWiese mine is `3.3.2` version, I saw your message on https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/390#issuecomment-1259036113, i couldnt find -ppv equivalent in that version lets wait from the author there